# Windows Store automatically installed on windows 10 enterprise LTSC

Tags: windows-10

Why and how was this program automatically installed on Windows ?!
I made no attempt to install the Windows Store!
There is a day now that it has been installed and it cannot be deleted!
Of course, I still do not want to delete it, but how is it installed? Very strange!

I added a few new images to show, for example, Cortana, video player, photo, etc. are not!

Also, check the installation date of Windows with the installation date of Windows Store!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is Windows Store automatically installed on windows 10 enterprise LTSC:
[image: Windows Store automatically installed on windows 10 enterprise LTSC]

Comment: The Windows Store is installed with Windows. You don't need to do anything to have it.

Comment: The reason it's installed is whomever generated your Windows image didn't remove it.  In reality the Enterprise Windows Store application was installed on the image. [Research](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/stop-employees-from-using-microsoft-store)

Comment: Now now, please take a step back. Windows 10 Enterprise __LTSC__ does _not_ contain Microsoft Store or any of the other consumer-oriented apps. [You can read about it here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-overview). So this question isn’t as absurd as you make it sound.

Comment: Thank you @DanielB .. I hate being ignorant when I think I am smart!  I am going to go eat some crow now. :^P

Comment: @harrymc No. here https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/ltsc-what-is-it-and-when-should-it-be-used/ba-p/293181 - Says it does not include any of these programs.

Comment: I stand corrected. It is still possible to install it manually, see [Add / Install Microsoft Store on Windows 10 LTSC or LTSB Editions](https://www.freesoftwaretips.tech/technology/add-install-microsoft-store-on-windows-10-ltsc-or-ltsb-editions/). Somehow some product you installed incorporated this same installer.

Comment: I only enabled the "Developer mode" option in the "for developer" settings! Otherwise, I would not have installed any program like this
Windows is still empty and I have not installed anything special yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have enabled the "Developer mode" option but have installed no other software.

When developer mode is turned on, a developer kit is automatically downloaded,
and does not require any user interaction for its installation.

It's interesting to note, although not documented anywhere, that your experience
indicates that the Windows Store is part of that kit.

This is perhaps because Developer mode allows using developer tools,
among which I find frequently mentioned WSL.
As WSL (and others) are loaded from the Windows Store, perhaps Microsoft was just
being helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is installed automatically by Microsoft along with Apps that are also installed automatically (Calculator, Photos, Windows 10 Mail and so on).

This is how Windows 10 works (and has done for a long time now). You do not need to do anything with the silent installations.

Store can be handy, Calculator is handy, so keep what you need in the Start Menu and remove items you do not need. That does not uninstall them.

If you really need to uninstall a specific app, there are power shell scripts to do that.

Comment: No no!
I came on purpose and installed this version of Windows to get rid of all the Windows add-ons and none of them are on Windows!
This version of Windows, according to Microsoft, was made or designed for this purpose!
But after a week, the Windows Store was installed! No other program was installed!
I could see that it was being installed! That is, like other Windows programs, it was being downloaded! Then it was installed! After installing the program, start running.
Well this should not happen!